# write boolean values as True or False to excel file using xlwt

Tags: python, django, boolean, export-to-excel, xlwt

I am using xlwt ([docs](http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)) for generating an excel sheet.I have used [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10332/) django snippet to do it. The only issue I am facing is I have a column in excel sheet which has boolean values which appear as 1 or 0 , but I want True or False. I tried many things like

```
DEFAULT_STYLE = xlwt.Style.default_style
```

and I also tried to force default style for this column as per article [here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966#xlwt.Worksheet.write-method) I think it is possible.I also tried to remove this line

```
(bool,          xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='BOOLEAN')),
```

to check if that would work but all in vain.
Plus docs were not much of help either.Can anybody suggest some changes to the snippet mentioned [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10332/) to allow boolean values to appear as True or False. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I know Its too late to answer this question.

I was also stuck with this problem today.

In Most of the cases this type of problem will fix using

**label= 'bool'**

according to doc https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/api.html

```
sheet.write(r, c, label='bool', style)
```

If it is not working for you then use 
**value** in string

```
sheet.write(row, col, str(value))
```